# Autocomplete not displaying image in mvc

Tags: jquery, razor, autocomplete

I am using autocomplete with image to search text box in razor.I am using following function to use jquery autocomplete

```
   $(function () {
            $("#small-searchterms").autocomplete({
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("SearchTermAutoComplete", "Home")', type: "GET",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { term: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                         return { Name: item.Name, id: item.id, value: '<img src="' + item.productpictureurl +'">' + ' '+item.label};
                            }))
                        }
                    })

                },
                minLength: 3,
                select: function (event, ui) {
                    var selecteditem = ui.item;
                    alert(selecteditem.id);

                }
            });

          return false;
      });
```

Autocomplete is working fine to display names but Instead of image autocomplete is showing image url.Is there any way to display image?
Thnkx for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `data('autocomplete')._renderItem`, like ,change to:

```
$("#small-searchterms").autocomplete({
      source: function (request, response) {
      $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Action("SearchTermAutoComplete", "Home")', type: "GET",
           dataType: "json",
           data: { term: request.term },
           success: function (data) {
              response($.map(data, function (item) {
                 return { 
                     Name: item.Name, 
                     id: item.id, 
                     value: item.productpictureurl,
                     label: item.label
                 };
               }))
           }
      })

      },
      minLength: 3,
      select: function (event, ui) {
           var selecteditem = ui.item;
            alert(selecteditem.id);

      }
   }).data('autocomplete')._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
       return $('<li>')
            .data('item.autocomplete', item)
            .append(item.label + '<img src="' + item.value + '" alt="" />')
            .appendTo(ul);
  };
```

For example:: See [custom render item implementation](https://gist.github.com/hernan/1409521)

Comment: I found out the problem was with version of jquery ui.I simply replaced autocomplete to uiautocomplete now the image is displayed.

Comment: glad you figured it out